# What is a native client?

Tags: c#, windows

What is a native client?

Is Native client same as thick client?

Can anybody explaing it for me?

Comment: Google can explain anything to you.

Comment: Sorry for repeats. My question was not per so std as its word count was less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nishakant, since you asked this in context of my tweet, let me explain what i meant by it. Native in that context meant a native Windows 8 application, which in turn means an application conforming to the new modern UI guidelines, runs on WinRT and is downloaded and installed from Windows 8 Store and runs locally on the Windows 8 machine. It isn't a web application, but locally installed. You could co-relate it to thick client applications in regular desktop world.

Additionally, this particular application is built by Twitter itself and hence another subtle meaning to the word native

Answer (score 2):

Native client for me traditionally means not interpreted by a virtual execution environment or sandbox but executed by the CPU and bound to the operating system (think Win32). I'd contrast native with HTML, JVM, CLR, etc.

Thick client for me traditionally means some business logic executing on the client, (think WPF, WinForms) as opposed to web/browser or other lightweight presentation container where most business logic is executing on the (web) server and minimal logic is executing on the client.

Traditionally, the two distinctions are unrelated, with "native clients" often being "thick". However, with the introduction of devices this distinction has become skewed, since it's not crystal clear anymore if a native app on a little device can still be considered thick. Many people avoid saying "thick" and refer to "rich" instead.

Answer (score 0):

While a native client may be about anything (for example a Native American paying you to write software for him), I'd say that in terms of software, a native client is some piece of software that is compiled to CPU bytecode, as opposed to a piece of software that's compiled to bytecode, which is compiled to CPU bytecode by an execution environment (Java, .NET, etc.) when run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that at present, the term Native Client is only used to refer to Google Native Client (NaCl), which is a tool for running native code from within a browser, and yes in this case, [Google definitely can explain it to you](https://developers.google.com/native-client/).

Comment: How is this answer related to the C# tag of this question?

Comment: @Mishax SO questions often have tags that don't actually relate to the question at hand. Expecially questions demonstrating as little research and detail as this one.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess since there is lack of context. I guess the Native Client you refered, is related to Google Chromium, is that right?

Chromium is an OS base on web browser, which means developer should NOT be able to go deeper than the browser. No directly manipulating the hardware, or optimizing your code in a CPU level, things like that.

However the requirement is there, so the Native Client is a technology, which provides a sandbox, to run the Native code(not really native, just you wrote with typical native language) inside the web browser.

You can see it's not same as Thick client.